# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion laravel

Tags: laravel

este error me aparece al momento de entrar en la direccion para visualizar mi lista de proveedores en formato json:

este es controlador que deberia de devolverme los datos:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

    $buscar = $request->buscar;
    $criterio = $request->criterio;

    if ($buscar==''){
        $personas = Proveedor::join('personas','proveedores.id','=','personas.id')
        ->select('personas.id','personas.nombre','personas.tipo_documento',
        'personas.num_documento','personas.direccion','personas.telefono',
        'personas.email','proveedores.contacto','proveedores.telefono_contacto')
        ->orderBy('personas.id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    }
    else{
        
        $personas = Proveedor::join('personas','proveedores.id','=','personas.id')
        ->select('personas.id','personas.nombre','personas.tipo_documento',
        'personas.num_documento','personas.direccion','personas.telefono',
        'personas.email','proveedores.contacto','proveedores.telefono_contacto')            
        ->where('personas.'.$criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
        ->orderBy('personas.id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    }
    return [
        'pagination' => [
            'total'        => $personas->total(),
            'current_page' => $personas->currentPage(),
            'per_page'     => $personas->perPage(),
            'last_page'    => $personas->lastPage(),
            'from'         => $personas->firstItem(),
            'to'           => $personas->lastItem(),
        ],
        'personas' => $personas
    ];
}
```

Comment: Nos ayudaría si indicas de manera exacta en que línea se genera dicho error

Comment: Estás regresando un arreglo en lugar de un String con la vista Que quieres. El arreglo debería ir como el segundo argumento del return, cómo la información que llegara a la vista.

Comment: como deberia quedar entonces?